# Unable to send POST request using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am unable to send POST request to my php file using AJAX. I have two files, the first one is index.php and second isVerificationStatusAPIV2.php. Contents of index.php are:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Phone Verification by Dial2Verify API V2 ( www.dial2verify.com )</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var attempt=1;
var transactionToken="";

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#enter_number").submit(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         initiateDial2Verify();
        });
    });

    function initiateDial2Verify() {
        showCodeForm(1); 
        GetVerificationImage();
    }

    function showCodeForm(code) {
        $("#dial2verify").fadeIn();
        $("#enter_number").fadeOut();
        $("#waiting_msg").text("Waiting for missed call from "+$("#phone_number").val());
    }

    function GetVerificationImage() {
        $.post("GetImageAPIV2.php", { phone_number : $("#phone_number").val() }, 
               function(data) { updateImage(data.img,data.transactionToken); }, "json");
    }



    function updateImage(img, vtransactionToken) {




                             $("#Image").html("Please give a missed call to <br><img src=\""+img+"\"/>");

                         transactionToken = vtransactionToken;
                         PollStart("0");
                            }


    function CheckStatus()
    {
        $.post("VerificationStatusAPIV2.php", { transactionToken : transactionToken }, 
               function(data) { PollStart(data.status); }, "json");
    }


    function PollStart(vStatus)
    {
                     attempt =attempt+1;
                     if ( attempt >= 90  ) { TimeoutCheck(); }  
                     else
                     if (vStatus === "0") { 
                        $("#status").html("Please give a missed call in  <b><i>"+(90-attempt) +"</i></b> seconds.");
                        setTimeout(CheckStatus, 1000);
                        }                        
                     else if (vStatus === "1")
                    {
                    success(); 
                    }
                    else
                    TimeoutCheck();

    }


            function Err() {
            $("#status").html("Error!<br>Sorry something went wrong, Please cross check your telephone number."); 
            }

    function success() {
        $("#status").text("Congrats !!! Phone Number Verified!");

    }

    function TimeoutCheck() {
        $("#status").text("Verification Failed!");
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="enter_number">
    <p>Enter your phone number:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verify" /></p>
</form>

<div id="dial2verify" style="display: none;">
    <p id="waiting_msg"></p>
    <p id="Image">Loading ..</strong></p>
            <p id="status">Loading ..</strong></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In function CheckStatus() I am sending a post request using AJAX to file VerificationStatusAPIV2.php but it isn't making any post request. can someone tell what's wrong in that?

*Update* I just saw that "status" in "data.status" in func CheckStatus() is in yellow color while others in blue color. maybe thats the problem?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to not use submit which you are trying to prevent, but instead just fire the relevant functions upon click ?

Comment: @RoyalBg Yes but my problem is I cant send post request (in CheckStatus() function).

Answer (score 0):

In your code snipped the only place you have `CheckStatus` exept for the function itselft is this line ... `setTimeout(CheckStatus, 1000);` so if this is the function call it'S should be like this : `setTimeout(CheckStatus(), 1000);`

This may be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 
`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verify" />`
to 
`<input type="submit" id="btn_enter" name="submit" value="Verify" />`

and in the js:

```
$("#btn_enter").submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     initiateDial2Verify();
    });
```

you were pointing your submit function to the HTML form's ID

```
var request=$.ajax({
   method:"POST",
   url:"VerificationStatusAPIV2.php",
   data:{ transactionToken : transactionToken },
   dataType:"json"
  });
request.success(function(data){
  PollStart(data.status);
});
```

Comment: That's not my problem. i said i cant send post request in CheckStatus() :/

Comment: @Sebastien.Beaulieu the parenthesis aren't necessary in a "SetTimeout" function

Comment: No but i am sure cuz i was using the same code for another purpose. instead i used data.message in checkstatus(). this time i am using data.status. and also my compiler shows status in yellow color and other things in blue color, may be thats the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are processing your php page as it should be?

Comment: Try printing out the AJAX call status

Comment: @CapitanFindus will do . btw as compiler shows 'status' in yellow color i think its a reserved keyword and its causing prob?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Try running your ajax function while using Google Chrome pressing CTRL+SHIFT+I, or Mozilla Firefox with Firebug on it, you will be able to see your ajax call progress and its php response